# Invalid default value for 'create_date' timestamp field

Tags: mysql

I have the following sql create statement

```
mysql> CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `erp`.`je_menus` (
    ->   `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    ->   `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
    ->   `description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    ->   `live_start_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    ->   `live_end_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL , 
    ->   `notes` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
    ->   `create_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    ->   `created_by` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
    ->   `update_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  ,
    ->   `updated_by` INT(11) NOT NULL , 
    ->   `status` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) 
    -> ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

giving following error

`ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'create_date'`

What is the error here?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your query and it works on  5.1.50-community just tested.

Comment: The query is okay in my end too.

Comment: Not Sure but give a different name to that field and try?

Comment: i use mysql 5.1.56 community in ubuntu 10.04. and not working

Comment: The no zero date requires a date.
Use '1970-01-01 00:00:01'.
[taken from here][1]


  [1]: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6171/invalid-default-value-for-datetime-when-changing-to-utf8-general-ci

Comment: I know many people don't like NULL fields in their databases, but isn't NULL (which means "unknown" or "undefined") here better than '0000-00-00'? That's like using `age = -1` instead of `age = NULL`

Answer (score 218, accepted):

That is because of server SQL Mode - [NO_ZERO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date).

From the reference: `NO_ZERO_DATE` - In strict mode, doesn't allow `'0000-00-00'` as a valid date. You can still insert zero dates with the *IGNORE* option. When not in strict mode, the date is accepted but a warning is generated.

Comment: how do i give ignore option?

Comment: You cannot ignore this option. This is server option. If you have access to my.ini (mysql configuration file), then remove NO_ZERO_DATE from sql-mode option and restart server.

Comment: To check this option - run SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'

Comment: i generated the script using mysql workbench. In the script the sql_mode is set to traditional. If I remove the traditional, the script works.

Comment: In MySQL Workbench preferences, go to tab 'Model: MySQL'. There set 'SQL_MODE to be used in generated scripts' to "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION" That solves the problem for good.

Comment: you can check your sql_mode using the commands (note there are two levels):
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;

Comment: If you do not have administation rights for the server, you can just set the sql mode for the session:
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

Answer (score 207):

If you generated the script from the MySQL workbench.

The following line is generated

```sql
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

Remove TRADITIONAL from the SQL_MODE, and then the script should work fine

Else, you could set the SQL_MODE as Allow Invalid Dates

```sql
SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you. SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'; was a life saver. I had this problem when I trie migrating a wordpress site to another server (both local) and it would not let me import the database data due to this error, even though there were no rows in the tables with this error.

Comment: SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'; did the trick before the executing the query

Comment: To get this to work in MySQL 8 I had to add global :  `SET GLOBAL SQL_MODE ='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';`

Answer (score 72):

TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC (see [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)).  The default value must be within that range.

Other odd, related, behavior:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (
    ts TIMESTAMP);  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

CREATE TABLE tbl2 (
    ts TIMESTAMP,
    ts2 TIMESTAMP);
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'ts2'

CREATE TABLE tbl3 (
    ts TIMESTAMP,
    ts2 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Side note, if you want to insert NULLS:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl4 (
    ts TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL);
```

Comment: This is happening to me. Wth is going on? ts2 is not even "NOT NULL"...!

Comment: Might be because "If you do not set a value for the first TIMESTAMP column in a table, MariaDB will automatically assign it the current date and time when performing an UPDATE or INSERT query on the row(s) in question." – [MariaDB Docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/timestamp/)

Comment: I like the use of `column_name TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()`.  May not be appropriate for every situation but thought I'd share since I was dealing with this too.

Comment: column_name TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01' did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me when adding a column with liquibase like so.
`<column defaultValueDate="1970-01-01 00:00:01" name="at" type="timestamp">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>`

Comment: @code_gamer worked for me. It was `request_date date NOT NULL DEFAULT 'current_timestamp()'` and I changed it to `request_date date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01'` The database was written for php 7.3 mysql 5.1 and I am using php 7.4 and mysql 5.7. Is there a way to update my sql file to suit mysql 5.7?

Comment: Main annoying thing for me is that this error message
Invalid default value for 'ts2' 
only appears for second column (ts2). Why the same error is not shown for first column (ts)?

Answer (score 48):

In ubuntu desktop 16.04, I did this:

1. open file: `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` in an editor of your choice.
2. Look for: `sql_mode`, it will be somewhere under `[mysqld]`.
3. and set `sql_mode` to the following:

   `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`
4. Save and then restart mysql service by doing:

   `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: It did helped, except that the `sql_mode` wasn't there for my instance of mySQL on ubuntu16.04. I had to add an entry for it in the file, by removing the "NO_ZERO_DATE". So, here is how it looks now:  #Adding the below line to get rid of no_zero_date 

sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Comment: you are right.. I added that earlier to disable the strict mode.. and when I edited it for this particular issue, the `sql_mode` entry was already there.

Comment: Is this a bug? CURRENT_TIMESTAMP should never return "0000-00-00 00:00:00", or I'm wrong? Why should I have to change mysqld settings?

Comment: @letsjump because someone configured your mysql server incorrectly. i'm hitting this issue with a database I imported. the default value for the timestamp in a column is not a valid timestamp value. the REAL fix is to update the default timestamp to something valid like 1970 - the earliest date available. The temporary workaround is to disable checking on the database.

Answer (score 27):

Just Define following lines at top of your Database SQL file.

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
```

It is working for me.

Answer (score 13):

Using **OS X**, install mysql from **Homebrew**, System Variables based on its compiled-in defaults. 
Solution is to remove "NO_ZERO_DATE" from System Variables "sql_mode".

Just please keep in mind that scope involve.

If you want to affect only in your session, please use `"@@session"`, For example:

```
SET @@session.sql_mode ="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION".
```

In this case, it will not affect once your session ends or your change it. It has not effect on other session.

If you want to affect on all client, please use `"@@global"`, for example:

```
SET @@global.sql_mode ="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION".
```

In this case, it only affects on the clients that connect after the change(not affect on current all clients), and will not work once server exit.

Answer (score 13):

To avoid this issue, you need to remove `NO_ZERO_DATE` from the mysql mode configuration.

1. Go to 'phpmyadmin'.
2. Once phpmyadmin is loaded up, click on the 'variables' tab.
3. Search for 'sql mode'.
4. Click on the Edit option and remove `NO_ZERO_DATE` (and its trailing comma) from the configuration.

This is a very common issue in the local environment with wamp or xamp.

Comment: When I restart Mamp they reappear

Comment: For my Mac, changing it in phpmyadmin as suggested didn't work, as the sql mode was reset when MAMP restarted.  As suggested from other searches, in /Applications/MAMP/conf, I created file my.cnf with the following content: `[mysqld] \n sql-mode="ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"`  (replace '\n' with a carriage return).  Cheers! jz

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue with MySQL 5.7 with the following code:

`` `update_date` TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ``

I fixed by using this instead:

`` `update_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ``

Comment: I think this is actually the best option for when it does make sense to default to current, it wouldn't however make sense for birth timestamp - just as an example.

Comment: You'll loose precision (milli-seconds)

Comment: I was using the data type `Int(11)`, `date` and this problem happens to me. As you said, I converted it to `TIMESTAMP` and it worked.  thanks

Answer (score 8):

I was able to resolve this issue on OS X by installing MySQL from Homebrew

```
brew install mysql
```

by adding the following to /usr/local/etc/my.cnf

```
sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

and restarting MySQL

```
brew tap homebrew/services
brew services restart mysql
```

Answer (score 3):

To disable strict SQL mode

```
Create disable_strict_mode.cnf file at /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

In the file, enter these two lines:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Finally, restart MySQL with this command:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
`create_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`update_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  ,
```

To the following:

```
`create_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
`update_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: If this is a WordPress site, please do no update the Core WordPress tables.  Many plugins expect a value of zeores, so WordPress cannot change this default value for legacy reasons that would break plugins. [Wordpress thread](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41785) and [Wordpress support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/invalid-default-value-for-user_registered/).  Changing database structure without familiarity of code relying on the default values can lead to troubling bugs.  While this may work as a solution in many cases, it could wreck havock in others. Not a universal solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have administation rights for the server, you can just set the sql mode for the current session:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Answer (score 2):

Default values should start from the year 1000.

For example,

```
ALTER TABLE mytable last_active DATETIME DEFAULT '1000-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Nope. The major issue is in incorrect default day and month values, which can't be 00 (there are no 0 month and 0 day).

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondered to see so many answers, but no one had specified main reason: incorrect "ZERO" date format. In short, just use **'0000-01-01 00:00:00'** instead of '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. Both month 00 and day 00 are not valid values, obviously.

I agree with top user that the error was caused by MySQL setting [NO_ZERO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date). This setting was introduced in new MySQL server releases to be enabled by default, surprisal for many developers. But please note that the main goal of this setting is not to make developers' life harder, but just force them to fix outdated table structures and avoid using such incorrect data structure format in future.

So, if you're creating new table and want to specify "ZERO" date, use '0000-01-01 00:00:00'.

If you have already created tables and obtaining this error (e.g. on inserting new records with omitting default value), just update your tables like that:

```
ALTER TABLE `erp`.`je_menus` 
MODIFY COLUMN `create_date` datetime(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-01-01 00:00:00'  AFTER `notes`;
```

Removing mentioned server setting is just temporarily solution and is not an example of good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to examine the timezone setting on the MySql instance:

```
mysql> show variables like 'time_zone';
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| time_zone     | SYSTEM |
+---------------+--------+
```

in my case, I realised that the underlying system had it's timezone set to BST rather than UTC, and so in the create table the default of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' was being coerced back 1 hour, resulting in an invalid timestamp value.

For me, I actually wanted the machine's timezone set to UTC, and that sorted me out. As I was running Centos/7, I simply did

```
# timedatectl set-timezone UTC
```

and restarted everything.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting in case anybody runs into the similar issue that I had using MySql 5.6.
I was receiving an invalid default error for the following line:

```
`last_observed_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
```

This shouldn't throw an error because the date is within unix time, *however*, the default time is **not** specified as unix time, but rather by whatever timezone your mysql database is set to use (in my case, SYSTEM time in Australia, which is GMT+10.

Because Australian Eastern Time is 10 hours ahead of GMT, '1970-01-01 00:00:01' converts to GMT (unix) time as '1969-12-30 14:00:01', which is an invalid datetime.

This can be solved either by setting the session or global time zone on mysql.

```
SET @@session.time_zone = '+00:00';
```

OR

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+00:00';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_actionscheduler_actions` CHANGE `scheduled_date_gmt` `scheduled_date_gmt` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CHANGE `scheduled_date_local` `scheduled_date_local` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CHANGE `last_attempt_gmt` `last_attempt_gmt` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CHANGE `last_attempt_local` `last_attempt_local` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score -2):

You could just change this:

```
`create_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

To something like this:

```
`create_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '2018-04-01 12:00:00',
```

Answer (score -2):

I try to set type of column as 'timestamp' and it works for me.

Answer (score -3):

You could just change this:

`create_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',

To something like this:

`create_date` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',