# Create table with default values giving error

Tags: mysql, constraints, default

Using MySql Workbench 6.3 Build version 6.3.6.
I am trying to create a table with Default constraint but its giving me error.

Here is the script

```
Create Table `Migration_Log2` (

                                    `Id` Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                    `FilePath` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
                                    `FileName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                                    `IsSent` bool NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                                    `CreatedDate` DateTime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                                    `ModifiedDate` DateTime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                                    `SendAttemptMade` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                                    `Message` Text  DEFAULT NULL,
                                     PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
                                      KEY `migration_log_Id_UNIQUE` (`Id`)
                                    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

> Error Message
>
> ## **Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'CreatedDate'   0.000 sec**

Comment: your query running fine . check this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/852935

Comment: in which mysql version?

Comment: This question will help you to get a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192027/invalid-default-value-for-create-date-timestamp-field

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to some strict constraint on the data type check on database server. 
I would suggest to change type of field `CreatedDate` from `datetime` to `timestamp`.

I had faced similar issue in a VPS for my website.

Answer (score 0):

Your CURRENT_TIMESTAMP might have been appending the microseconds in the output.

Try to use: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) as the default value.

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(1), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2);
```

The microseconds mattered, possibly. See the differences.

Comment: 1. What about changing datetime to timestamp for CreatedDate column?
2. Try changing from utf8 to Latin for a test. It can be also a reason.
3. But you should see your error message too.

Comment: Hey Bimal, can u try at ur end and let me know because I tired everything and infact even from UI is not allowing   http://i66.tinypic.com/142rbl2.jpg

Comment: Your original script from the problem itself runs OK in my mysql 5.6 version. Just tried to guess what any other configurations are different in your server settings.