# Mysql Error Code: 1067 two timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xyz` (
   `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   `start_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   `end_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) 
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Running the above mysql script results in:
Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'start_time'.
**The error is most likely due to two TIMESTAMP column in one table**

Similar answer to this question is vague. [Invalid default value for 'create_date' timestamp field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192027/invalid-default-value-for-create-date-timestamp-field)

**I need a clear solution.**

Answer (score 1):

You've missed backticks `` ` `` before `xyz`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xyz` (
   `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   `start_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   `end_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Rather than answering such typo questions, just vote to close them.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Maybe not a typo question to OP, we can not suppose everyone would have been very familiar with `mysql`, and OP have tried to search answers, but he or she did not get it. Maybe I should take this answer as a comment, but I hold a reservation about voting to close.

Comment: @Forward Sorry about the typo, the error wasn't typo. The error is most likley due to two TIMESTAMP column in one table.