# live MySQL db accepts 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" as datetime value - local does not

Tags: php, mysql

I've picked up on a project that's a few years old, and noted CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is being sent with a lot of the php calls to update the datetime field in a lot of rows. This works perfectly on the live environment - however, on my local setup, it does not.

Both the Live DB, and my local version from the WAMP64 download are running on MySQL5.7.19.

A PHP script running a query that involves inserting CURRENT_TIMESTAMP will return back with the following error;

```
Invalid default value for 'last_update' timestamp
```

Again though, on the live server, this works without issue. Both are using MySQLi to carry out these insert queries.

Is there something I'm missing here? Some sort of server-side config setting that allows CURRENT_TIME to be inserted into the timestamp field?

Comment: Have you tried using using `SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';`?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: It sounds like your local version of MySQL has [`explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp) set to false?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Are both running 5.7.19?  And did you upgrade versions recently?

Comment: Can you show those queries please with emphasis on the values that you're trying to insert into the column that represents the current timestamp ?

Comment: Present your [MCVE]. There is no reason for `NOW()` to be rejected for a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` field (which is it?). The error likely comes from a _different_ field for which you did not provide a value, then the behaviour relies on [`explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp). But we cannot answer until you show us the problematic SQL and schema.

Answer (score 2):

The `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` field automatically pick the current time of server.or will only accept the timestamp values.

So `DATETIME` fields must be left either with a null default value, or no default value at all - default values must be a constant value, not the result of an expression.

relevant docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

You can work around this by setting a post-insert trigger on the table to fill in a "now" value on any new records.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps database lost the default value for the date. You can try either of the following:

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable MODIFY myfield datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Or

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable MODIFY myfield datetime DEFAULT NOW();
```

Answer (score 1):

The specific column must be missing in the insert statement because the error message stated `Invalid default value`. 
Please take a look at: [Invalid default value for 'create_date' timestamp field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192027/invalid-default-value-for-create-date-timestamp-field) (and read the helpful comments here). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are inserting the last_update value manually from php code then make the mysql filed as var-char as you passing the date is not recognize by database as date and this error is occurring.
2. Or you can just set the default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and set attribute as on update insert CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
   [image]

So that when ever any update on filed it will update the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP automatically.