# How do I add a new column to MySQL via phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Coming from years of experience with MS SQL Server I though it would be easy to add a simple nullable integer column to a MySQL database table using phpMyAdmin. I simply found the part of the UI that most resembled the part of SSMS where a new column is added to a table in SQL Server, clicked add column, entered a name, selected int, and null for default value.

[image]
The table itself is a posts table created by WordPress. When I click save I get an error saying

> ALTER TABLE 'wp_posts' ADD 'acserp' INT NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER 'comment_count';

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1067 - Invalid default value for 'post_date'

I really don't see what adding an integer column has to do the the `post_date` column unless some row in the posts table has an invalid value for `post_date` and mySQL does some sort of checks to make sure that noting is wrong with the rest of the table before adding anything.

Comment: How did you create the rest of the table, and are there any triggers in place?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer is that you have to use raw SQL queries and tweak the SQL_Mode setting.

SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD new_table INT AFTER comment_count

[Invalid default value for 'create_date' timestamp field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192027/invalid-default-value-for-create-date-timestamp-field)

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to define **Length/Value** of the integer field. It is the third column from the left. Give value to it and your issue will be resolved. Read [this](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-data-types.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes